# MySQL InnoDB row locking is unexprected zero

Tags: mysql, sql, locking, innodb, myisam

```
mysql> show global status like 'table_locks%';
+-----------------------+--------+
| Variable_name         | Value  |
+-----------------------+--------+
| Table_locks_immediate | 433856 |
| Table_locks_waited    | 22     |
+-----------------------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show global status like '%innodb_row_lock_%';
+-------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                 | Value |
+-------------------------------+-------+
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits | 0     |
| Innodb_row_lock_time          | 0     |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg      | 0     |
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max      | 0     |
| Innodb_row_lock_waits         | 0     |
+-------------------------------+-------+
```

I want to use row level locking when update records. Here's my SQL looks like:

```
String insertSQL = "insert into t_example(" + field_list
                + ") values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "
                + "on duplicate key update "
                + ... ...
                + "field9 = VALUES(field9), "
                + "field10 = VALUES(field10)";
```

According to MySQL's [Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) :

*INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE on a partitioned table using a storage engine such as MyISAM that employs table-level locks locked all partitions of the table. (**This did not and does not occur with tables using storage engines such as InnoDB that employ row-level locking.**)*

My table `t_example` is using InnoDB of course.

I thought my insertion would use row level locking a lot. But `innodb_row_lock` is actually zero.

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect?

You do not use a transaction I assume? You therefore do not lock any rows with an `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` statement, which other transaction should have to wait for.

A single INSERT/UPDATE statement will likely not block, because it's fast (insert should be fast and updating with searching for a violated unique index is fast too).

Since the queried innodb status variables do not count, but only show you times and waits and you likely did not have any waits with any waiting time, this is output I would expect.

You can try two transactions by using two clients. Client 1

```
BEGIN;
SELECT something FROM table FOR UPDATE;
```

without(!) exiting Client 1 try to select the same row in a second client. This should result in a wait and should be displayed in innodb status.

Selecting another row, which you did not lock in client 1, should be able without a wait.